# Mapping x,y,z coordinates to one integer

Tags: mapping

I want to create a function in order to convert x,y,z to one number.

For example, I have created a function for x,y to one number. Let's say the number is "k" and width, the width of the map. k=y*width+x.

I think that a good idea would be to consider it as an x,y model, but in each position there is an imaginary array with the elements and the index of the array is z.

How should the function be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up a maximum number of digits per axis it should be easy:

k = x + (y * 10^MAX_DIGITS_X) + (z * 10^(MAX_DIGITS_X + MAX_DIGITX_Y))

Comment: how ' 10^max digits x ' comes out? i mean why 10?

Comment: Because I assumed x, y and z are base 10, if you are using hex you could use 16 instead. That way you avoid that the value of x never will get into the digits used to store the value of y. Let say you have (x,y,z) = (11,25,2). With max digits = 2 for the three axis. So you end up with 22511. If you use 9 you won't be able to extract x, y and z from your number deterministically.